# Disassembling shared library - which version is shown?

Tags: gdb, shared-libraries

I'm using gdb to debug an intermittent crash.  I can open the core dump, and see that the crash occurred inside a shared library.  (I can see the function names and the file name of the library in the backtrace, though I don't have the source code for the library.)

Meanwhile, the library has been updated, so that file name now holds a different version of the library than the one that was loaded when the core dump was generated.

I can run `disassemble` to see the machine code for the function where the crash occurred - but would I see the code from the version in use when the crash occurred, or will gdb load the code from the library file on disk, thereby picking a mismatching version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> would I see the code from the version in use when the crash occurred, or will gdb load the code from the library file on disk, thereby picking a mismatching version?

The latter (mismatched version).

By default, executable (and other read-only mappings) are *not* saved in the `core` to save space -- the contents *is* already available on disk.

On Linux you can ask your system to save read-only mappings with:

```
echo 0x7 > /proc/self/coredump_filter
```

See `man 5 core`.